# What is the Max file system size limit -Ubuntu KVM

Tags: 14.04

There were VMs which was created using 5TB disk size in the flavor but getting only 2TB for file system when VM is spawning.

Is there any limit for maximum file system size for VM which are running in KVM or any other issue with these environment.

Current 2TB limitation belong to MBR partition tables, those are not able to address more than 2TB of data.

As we can’t use MBR tables for 5TB disk , we have been checking the option of define GPT partition 
 tables by cloud-init definition, for that We tried using the following user data file

```
disk_setup: 
   /dev/vda: 
     table_type: 'gpt' 
     layout: 
       - 10 
       - 90 
     overwrite: true 

 fs_setup: 
   - label: root_fs 
     filesystem: 'ext4' 
     device: /dev/vda 
     partition: vda1 
     overwrite: true 
   - label: data_disk 
     filesystem: 'ext4' 
     device: /dev/vda 
     partition: vda2 
     overwrite: true
```

But, this commands wasn’t executed in Instance creation, We realized that  “disk_setup” module is 
 not loaded in cloud init, that is, inside VM file ” /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg” not appear the module 
 loaded, appeared in the following:

```
 cloud_config_modules: 
 - mounts 
 - locale 
 - set-passwords 
 - rh_subscription 
 - yum-add-repo 
 - package-update-upgrade-install 
 - timezone 
 - puppet 
 - chef 
 - salt-minion 
 - mcollective 
 - disable-ec2-metadata 
 - runcmd
```

And should be

```
 cloud_config_modules: 
 - disk_setup 
 - mounts 
 - locale 
 - set-passwords 
 - rh_subscription 
 - yum-add-repo 
 - package-update-upgrade-install 
 - timezone 
 - puppet 
 - chef 
 - salt-minion 
 - mcollective 
 - disable-ec2-metadata 
 - runcmd
```

After change that, we removed all files from /var/lib/cloud/ and rebooted the instance to force 
 cloud-init execution, in that moment GPT partition table modification  is executed but filesystem 
 configuration was not,  We made the filesystem configuration manually and we were able of have 5TB 
 disk in use. But the bad part is, due to this Instance is using BIOS (SeaBIOS) and not UEFI,  after 
 modify partition table to GPT, VM instance isn’t able to boot again.

For this reason, we need  your support by checking correct configuration of cloud-init to execute 
 all commands defined in user data file in VM instance creation.

NAME=Mitaka on Ubuntu 14.04